# Is there a way I can create an "Authorized" image that only partner websites can display?

Tags: asp.net, .net, image, browser, security

I'd like to create an image that states a website has been inspected and authorized by me and allow partner sites to display this image, but prevent others from displaying the image.  I was thinking I could host the image and ask partners to pass a token in the src attribute.  I could then look up the partner and check the referrer domain name matches my registry.  However, can't someone still download the image from a partner site and just serve it from there own server and defeat this?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Set ASP.Net in IIS to handle the type of image file you are using (.jpg, .png) and then write an HttpHandler to process those images and add a watermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop someone from downloading an image.

You can put text in the image to say "click here to verify", then have that popup a page on your site which verifies the IP of the referrer.

Comment: This is a good idea and will certainly help. People should have an easy way on your site to verify that a partner is in good standing. Also, your image should be easy to associate with the name of your site by a reasonably logical person. Your next biggest recourse, however, is going to be legal rather than technical. Find out about how to protect logos and aggressively go after infringers.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

That is a pretty good solution, but you're right the token isn't enough.  But, since each http request for an image comes with an http_referrer, you could combine the referred + token.  If the image is just completely the same you don't even need a token.  The biggest problem would be, when I go to the website, I could just download the image and host it where ever I want.  Unless the image is dynamic with information about the website it's on, it really can't be protected.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if an end user of one of your partner sites can see your image, then they can download it and serve it themselves. You can make it more of a nuisance for them, but you'd need to spend an awful lot of effort just to make a competent power-user take a few extra minutes in trying to download it.

The common solution to this sort of thing is by legal channels: you send lawyer-nastygrams to anyone who hosts your image without your consent, and hope that they obey.

If you wanted to get more hardcore, you could make individual images for each partner that included the partner name *in the image*, and distribute PGP signatures for each authentic image. Your images could include a short URL to somewhere on your site where they can be verified cryptographically, if anyone cares to do so.